# Should I use Node express for production?

Tags: node.js, windows, express, server

I wonder if it's safe to use node express for production server?

Just to run `node server.js` in the cmd window (in windows 2012 server) on the server?

If not, what are the available alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `pm2` in production for running `node.js` app.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you mean by "safe".

If it's security or stability, it's ultimately down to the application author to ensure that it's secure and stable.

However, if you mean stability in terms of the process running on the server, you have a couple of options.

[PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) is a fantastic Node.js process manager. You simply tell PM2 to run your code and it goes and does it. You can stream logs, stop, start, restart and it all plugs nicely into the PM2 web interface (really nice if you have lots of Node.js apps running!). I have personally used PM2 for about 6 months now and I've not had a single problem. It also will restart your app if it crashes and enables you to auto-start apps when the system reboots.

If your web host supports [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) (basically, anything that's not shared hosting), you could put your app inside a container and run it like that. Docker is a whole different ball game but it does allow you to run your apps really easily and not worry so much about security as it's (theoretically) all inside it's own container.

**Note: Linux only**

Run it using init scripts. You can run your app as a system service, just like [Ghost](http://support.ghost.org/deploying-ghost/#init-script) does. This allows it to run them when the system comes back from a reboot, assign a specific user to run it (good for security if used correctly). I don't really use init scripts for one main reason - it's more complex. When you're running lots of small-scale microservices, there isn't really any need to go full blown with init scripts. However, if you want to go down that route, there is a good overview [here](https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-linux-daemons-init-scripts).

These aren't the only solutions, but they're the ones I know most about. I'd be interested to see what other people use!

To conclude, I would suggest using PM2 to get your apps up and running to start with and only expand into init scripts if you really think it's necessary.

Happy deploying!

Answer (score 2):

I run some node apps in production using the [process manager PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). It restarts the app if it stops for any reason, and can get your app to run as a service (so the app will start on server boot-up). It's great, works like a charm, has some nice features like monitoring mode (so you can see you apps console log in real-time) and is straight forward to use. Check it out.

One thing I wish I knew before getting too involved with Node, is that not many shared hosting providers support it. Meaning you either need to implement a work-around, get a VPS instead, or use A2 hosting, which has the only shared hosting plan I found supporting Node out of the box.

If I'd known this before starting, I would probably have still used Node for all my projects, because I like it, but it would have been nice to know what I was getting into instead of getting a nasty shock when I came to deploy my first projects.

Comment: So what do you use instead?

Comment: Do you mean for hosting? I use contabo.com. I've been with them for ages, and haven't looked at the market for several years. But I'm sure there are plenty of other VPS options available.